# SQL - If dates don't match during join - change date then join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am using POSTGRESQL and am creating a table that joins adwords data and salesforce data to get a complete view of my metrics from cost/impressions to form fills within salesforce (campaign member records). We can join these two things (salesforce and adwords) with a UTM Parameter, this UTM Parameter is the "adgroup" value in adwords and becomes the "marketing_content_stamp__c" in salesforce. The issue is that we've created a cookie which says "If this person is organic, look for the stored UTM values in the persons cookie from the last date they were here". This creates a problem in that sometimes we have form fills in salesforce with a date that the adgroup has no records for.

What I want to do: 
Join the tables and say that "If a form fill exists on my table "temp.adwords_sf" and the adgroup table has no records for that date, join the record to the last adgroup record date."

For example I have a formfill for my ADGROUPX on the date of 11/13, but the last records in which I have clicks is 11/11. I want to make it so that formfill record is associated with 11/11 or else it will not show up.

SQL QUERY:

```
drop table temp.adwords_ui;
Create table temp.adwords_ui as(
Select 
cast(date as date),
Case 
WHEN adgroup like '%-uk-%' then 'UK'
WHEN adgroup like '%-usa-%' then 'USA'
WHEN adgroup like '%-us-%' then 'USA'
END AS Target_Country,
Case 
WHEN adgroup like '%-product-social%' then 'Product-SocialNetworks'
WHEN adgroup like '%-product-solu%' then 'Product-Solutions'
WHEN adgroup like '%-brand-%' then 'Brand'
WHEN adgroup like '%-competitors-%' then 'Competitors'
END AS ad_grouping,
adgroup,
sum(adcost) as cost,
sum(impressions) as impressions,
sum(adclicks) as clicks
from rjm_current.adwords45309635_v2
where adcost <> 0 
and date > '11/3/2015'
group by 1,2,3,4);


drop table temp.adwords_sf;
Create table temp.adwords_sf as (
Select
id,
campaign_name__c as campaign,
marketing_content_stamp__c as marketing_content,
cast(firstrespondeddate as date) as form_fill_date,
count(*) as form_fills
from rjm_current.sf_campaignmember
where marketing_source_stamp__c = 'google-adwords'
and firstrespondeddate > '11/3/2015'
group by 1,2,3,4); 


drop table custom.adwords;
Create table custom.adwords as (
select
a.date,
a.target_country,
a.ad_grouping,
a.adgroup,
b.campaign,
a.cost,
a.impressions,
a.clicks,
b.form_fills
--((a.cost) / nullif(a.clicks,0)) as CPC,
--(a.clicks / a.impressions) as CTR,
--((a.cost) / nullif(b.form_fills,0)) as Cost_per_FormFill
from temp.adwords_ui a
Left Join temp.adwords_sf b on a.adgroup = b.marketing_content
and cast(a.date as date) = cast(b.form_fill_date as date)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's going to be messy...

You can identify the 'missed' rows by changing that into a right join, then adding a 'where a.date is null'

Add to that a column for each 'a' column, with a subquery like below (example for date column)

```
(select top 1 date 
from a where date < b.form_filled_date 
and a.adgroup = b.marketing_content
order by date desc) as a_date,

(select top 1 target_country
from a where date < b.form_filled_date 
and a.adgroup = b.marketing_content
order by date desc) as a_target_country,
```

Write the above into a temp table, Then smudge those onto the end of the the custom table!

Hopefully something to get you started anyway...

Comment: That would be weird though. So that would have to be a subquery on EVERY field?? Just seems like there needs to be a better way.

Comment: It is a bit, but I think it's the only way to achieve it, you're trying to join on an inequality, which isn't something it's supposed to do. I just did something similar making a 'sessionaliser'  script to link individual web log hits to sessions.  If you want to move away from pure SQL, I have a small script that iterates through the records and populates a link table, joining the 'hits' table to the 'sessions' table,  this runs once a day so the performance is less important.

Comment: Just thinking about it again.. you need to do the above for JUST the columns that make up the primary key, and then use that in a join to bring in all the other fields.